# Alinear por columnas string en python

Tags: python, string, numpy, formato, text

Estoy haciendo uso de la función `np.array2string` para generar texto de un array, el problema lo tengo en que el texto que produce no tiene alineadas y justificadas las columnas. He buscado info sobre la propia función, en `np.printoptions` o `np.set_printoptions` y no me ha parecido ver ningún argumento para conseguir lo que busco. Se que el delimitador para que me alinee las columnas es `"f, "`, puesto que es lo que me separa un valor de otro en las filas. Pongo un ejemplo del output que me produce original y como quisiera que se me ordenara (son imágenes puesto que es bastante grande el texto)

Así es como me sale el texto (se trata de una variable de tipo *string*, no de un texto sacado por consola):
[image: Texto original tipo variable string]

Y así es como me gustaría que generara el string:
[image: Texto ordenador como me gustaría. Tipo variable string]

El código que he utilizado para que me guarde el array en una variable de tipo `string` es:

```
np.printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize, linewidth=300, supress=True)
AT_s = np.array2string(AT, precision=None, separator='f, ', formatter={'float_kind':lambda x: "%.1f" % x},
                       floatmode="maxprec")
AT_s = AT_s.replace("[", "{").replace("]", "}")
```

¿Quizá el truco este en una vez generado el string original (imagen 1) volcar el texto en un fichero `csv` utilizando como delimitador `".f, "` ?

Comment: Aclarame. ¿AT es un arreglo bidimensional [[0.f, 1.f, ...], [...]]? ¿quieres que cada columna se alinee con el mínimo espacio requerido, segun el contenido de cada columna? ¿quieres que el ancho necesario se determine dinamicamente? Supongo que te serviria algo que toma AT directamente (no AT_s)?

Comment: Hola. Si, AT es un arreglo bidimensional del tipo numpy.array .En definitiva, lo que me gustaría es que todos los ".f " de cada columna quedaran alineados.

Comment: Te invito a leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), te informarás de la manera adecuada de plantear una pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que ya tienes la matriz AT con los valores numéricos calculados, la idea es construir una función que genere una matriz de strings. Cada string tiene el valor numérico editado, de tal manera que dentro de una columna, todos los strings tienen el mismo ancho.

Con esta matriz de string puedes generar cualquier otro resultado textual de tu conveniencia.

La función es:

```
def matrix_format(matriz, formato):
    """ Genera una matriz de strings con columnas alineadas
    
    @param matriz: Una matriz de valores numericos.
    @param formato: Formato de impresión a aplicar a cada valor
    @return Una matriz de strings, con los valores editados y
    alineados por la derecha. Cada columna tiene el mínimo 
    ancho requerido según su contenido.
    """
    n_rows = len(matriz)
    n_cols = len(matriz[0])

    #
    # Determinar el máximo ancho necesario por columna.
    #
    col_max_width = []
    for col in range(n_cols): # Examinar la columna.
        max_width = 0 # Maximo ancho en esta columna
        for row in range(n_rows):
            # Formatear el valor en la celda para 
            # determina su ancho.
            edit_value = formato % matriz[row][col]
            max_width = max(max_width, len(edit_value))
        col_max_width.append(max_width)

    #
    # Ahora que sabemos el ancho necesario por columna,
    # generar la matriz de salida ajustando los anchos
    # de cada valor editado.
    #
    salida = []
    for row in range(n_rows):
        edit_row = []
        for col in range(n_cols):
            #  Primero editar el valor con su formato.
            edit_value = formato % matriz[row][col]
            #  Calcular el numero de espacios para ajustar
            #  a la derecha el valor editado
            edit_space = " "*(col_max_width[col] - len(edit_value))
            edit_row.append("%s%s" % (edit_space, edit_value))
        salida.append(edit_row)
    
    return salida
```

Hagamos un ejemplo:

```
AT = [[1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0, 110000.0],
      [5.0, 150.0, 5000.0, 6000.0, 40000.0],
      [100.0,20.0, 520.0, 70000.0, 500.0]]

salida = matrix_format(AT, " %.1ff")
for row in salida:  
    for col in row:  
        print(col, end="")
    print()
```

Produce

```
   1.0f  10.0f  100.0f  1000.0f 110000.0f
   5.0f 150.0f 5000.0f  6000.0f  40000.0f
 100.0f  20.0f  520.0f 70000.0f    500.0f
```

Ahora solo te queda "embellecer" la salida, agregando las ",", "{", y "}", pero ya tienes la parte fundamental, que son las columnas alineadas.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Voy a probar el método!

Comment: Funciona a la perfección. Justo como quería. Muchas gracias! ;)

Comment: El OP solo adjunto el código de cuando estaba generando los strings, tu generaste una función que realiza el trabajo de el y no tiene nada que ver con lo que el OP estaba **intentando**. Le hiciste todo el trabajo. ;)